# Boot from a OS on a separate partition via Plop boot manager?

Tags: linux, boot, virtual-machine, vmware, multi-boot

If I install a linux OS on a separate partition, would I be able to boot that partition using VMWare (via Plop boot manager)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both bootloaders, when so configured, allow you to boot one of several operating systems installed in separate partitions.

See examples for both [grub](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config) and for [plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/examples.html)

Comment: Sorry my question has not been clear. I have changed it.